# How do I fix the "Specified path is too long" error?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, appdata

I know this is a site for questions mostly about programming, and since I'm trying to fix this error for a programming reason I feel this is a fit place to ask this, I'm trying to install the ProDG Visual Studio 2010 Integration, and everytime I try to install it I get this error

"The specified path length is too long: C:\ProgramData\Application Data\Microsoft

I've looked thoroughly around the web, and found other people have had the same problem but I can't seem to find one that can fix my issue, I can't access the C:\ProgramData\Application Data\ folder because it says my access is denied, after further looking into the Application Data issue I saw stuff about the %appdata% method into accessing it, but still can't figure out how to fix my problem, so do any of you know how to fix this?  I am on Windows 8

Comment: Describe your problem in more details. It is not clear what do you mean. Is your path wrong? Is this permissions problem?

Comment: Yes it kinda is permission problems, because I cant change the path name or anything because access is either denied, or it just gives me an error saying the action can't be completed because the folder or a file in the folder is open in another program

Comment: I can make a VERY wild guess: could it be that you are facing problems due to Windows's Virtual Store? In this case I think a solution could be to run the installer as administrator. But please keep in mind that this suggestion could be **completely** wrong.

Comment: I have ran it as Admin and it doesn't make any difference, I need a way to change the file path length